# WebLogic Upgrade from 10.0.0 to 10.3.0

Tags: weblogic

Anyone have try to upgrade weblogic 10.0.0 to 10.3.6 Linux version ? Any document to follow? i tried download the upgrade installer but it cannot find the path.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to install 10.3.6 and upgrade the domains if possible. If you want to use upgrade installer then below links might be helpful.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e14142/prepare.htm#WLSIG105

http://xmlandmore.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-download-weblogic-upgrade.html